# JMonkey scrolling 3D text

Tags: 3d, jmonkeyengine, text

I need to make a scrolling 3D text, which is not a gui. I have a 3d box display over which I should render a long scrolling text. I can render and move text, but how do I cut/make invisible the part that goes out of the display area?

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: No, as far as my ideas go, it should be possible to render text in a separate bitmap, and use that as a texture, but that is a bit messy.

Comment: do you know how texture UV work? I think by slowly changing its UV value could do the trick, not sure tho.

Comment: also, I think [ImagePainter.jar](http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/t/image-painter-plugin-available/24255) may help on modifying the bitmap to achieve that too.

Comment: Yes, UV could do the trick, but still I would need to render a bitmap image.

Comment: you can put that bitmap modified by imagepainter on a texture (I think you can have a main bitmap and copy parts of it to the texture, giving move sensation but I think it is not the best way, cpu intensive [not sure tho]) and use it as material to your geometry